# HBase doesn't store all records

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I have 1.2M records at my **MongoDB** database. And I want to store all of this data at **HBase** programmatically. Basically I try to put each retrieved record to HBase in a loop. After the operation is finished, I got **only 39912** records on HBase.

*Here's what I've tried:*

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
String tableName = "storedtweet";
String familyName = "msg";
String qualifierName = "msg";
HTable table = new HTable(config, tableName);
// using Spring Data MongoDB to interact with MongoDB
List < StoredTweet > storedTweetList = mongoDAO.getMongoTemplate().findAll(StoredTweet.class);
for (StoredTweet storedTweet: storedTweetList) {
    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(storedTweet.getTweetId()));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes(familyName), Bytes.toBytes(qualifierName), Bytes.toBytes(storedTweet.getMsg()));
    table.put(p);
    table.flushCommits();
}
```

Comment: Can you check if some records have the same tweet id? If so, the later record will override the former.

Comment: thank you so much @zsxwing, I thought maybe it can still insert records despite duplication. It'd be better if you post this comment as answer to guide others. Then I'll mark it as "answer of question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some row key exists and you put it again, HBase Put will override the former. I think there are some records having the same tweet id (you set it to the row key) in your data. That's why some records disappear.